# Prompt for Confirmation Before DELETE or DROP Commands in PostgreSQL's psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I often run DELETE commands in PostgreSQL's psql when I intend to execute SELECT due to their similar syntax. To prevent accidental data loss, I'm seeking a way for psql to automatically prompt me for confirmation before executing any DROP or DELETE commands within a session. If there are alternative methods to achieve this, I would be glad to hear them. Thanks in advance!
A flag like prompt -x to suppress confirmation during numerous delete/drop queries would also be a great feature.

My PostgreSQL version:

```
david@david-comp:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.8 (Ubuntu 14.8-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
```

ChatGPT provided this bash function, but it operates only during a bash shell session:

```
function safe_psql() {
  while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *"DROP"* || $line = *"DELETE"* ]]; then
      echo "You're about to execute a DROP or DELETE statement: $line"
      echo "Do you want to proceed? (yes/no)"
      read -r answer
      if [[ $answer = "yes" ]]; then
        echo "$line" | psql $@
      fi
    else
      echo "$line" | psql $@
    fi
  done
}
```

I could add this function to my ~/.bashrc file to run it automatically, but I'd prefer a solution that operates solely within a psql session in order to keep my bashrc file clean. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you type `BEGIN` in a psql session, it starts a transaction, and won't commit changes until you type `COMMIT`. Other than that, I can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: Run `psql` with `--single-step` per (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)L *Run in single-step mode. That means the user is prompted before each command is sent to the server, with the option to cancel execution as well. Use this to debug scripts.*.

Comment: There is also [pgcli](https://www.pgcli.com/) a `psql` clone that has a conf setting of `destructive_warning = True` which from here [parseutils](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/blob/main/pgcli/packages/parseutils/__init__.py)   includes `BASE_KEYWORDS =["drop"   "shutdown", "delete", "truncate",    "alter",    "unconditional_update",]`